# haskell print multiple variables by pattern

Tags: haskell

I started writing answers to [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems in Haskell like so

```
problem1 = ...

problem2 = ...
```

to display them all together I've been using something like this

```
problems x = "print $ zip [1..] [" ++ intercalate "," (take x stringList) ++ "]"
             where
               stringList = map ("fromIntegral problem"++) stringInts
               stringInts = map show [1..]

main = print $ zip [1..] [fromIntegral problem1,fromIntegral problem2,...] (copy-pasta from ghci'ing problems string)
```

Is there a way to do this without copy pasting?

I looked into defining macros with m4 but I was having trouble getting problemi to translate to problem1. m4 also had problems with the infix operator backticks like

```
x `mod` 3 == 0
```

so I had to wrap the whole rest of the document in m4 block comments

I looked into defining c preprocessor macros but as far as I can tell for loops (or loops at all) aren't supported

I'm hoping there's a Haskell way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to display them all at once? It doesn't seem like an useful thing to do, really.

Anyway, you can change the interface a bit, and instead of `(problem1, problem2, ...) :: (Integral a) => a` do `problem :: (Integral a) => Int -> a`:

```
problem 1 = ...
problem 2 = ...
```

Then collecting all the problems is:

```
problems = zipWith ($) (repeat problem) [1..2]
main = print $ zip [1..] problems
```

Comment: It may seem a little counter-intuitive but I use it to compare execution speeds with different languages. It helps me understand what languages are fastest as best as I know how to code and optimize in that language